# Second column is the tallest instead of the first one when using column-count

Tags: css, multiple-columns, column-count

The second column seems to be filled first/to be the tallest, at least on certain screen sizes (as seen [here](https://codepen.io/elisagilis/pen/MWXdpKp)). How can I make sure the first column is filled in first and and the second column last (as it would make sense in the English language, reading from left to right)?

Note: I cannot use a set height in this case.

```html
<ul class="list--underline-large">
    <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</li>
    <li>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
    <li>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
    <li>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
    <li>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</li>
    <li>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
    <li>It to make a type specimen book.</li>
    <li>It to make a type specimen book.</li>
    <li>It to make a type specimen book.</li>
</ul>
```

```css
.list--underline-large {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 80px;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.list--underline-large li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #143b38;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 0 0 30px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.list--underline-large {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 80px;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.list--underline-large li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #143b38;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 0 0 30px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list--underline-large">
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</li>
  <li>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
  <li>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
  <li>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
  <li>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</li>
  <li>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
  <li>It to make a type specimen book.</li>
  <li>It to make a type specimen book.</li>
  <li>It to make a type specimen book.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you should try using grid instead or flex box. Which is much more easier to control.

Comment: @TohirulIslam this is CSS columns, not either grid or flex.

Comment: In your given case, what would you want it to look like? It seems to me that browsers are trying to balance the columns' lengths in the best way they can. In your case would you want the element which shows at the top of column 2 to be split over the two columns?

Comment: @AHaworth I can't have an element be split over 2 columns unfortunately. I'd like for elements not to be split over columns and for the columns to be as balanced as possible while keeping the reading direction left to right – so in this case 5 elements in the first column, 6 in the second. It doesn't make sense to have the second column longer than the first, which is what is happening right now. I could use 2 divs and split the content into columns myself instead, but I thought surely they'd be a solution to this that allows me to use CSS columns?

Comment: I think it's doing it's best to get things as balanced as they can be. Running your snippet if it were to force the left column to be longer it could turn out to be very much longer (because what would otherwise be at the top of col 2 would be pushed down to col1, and it could be very long). If that is what you are after then I think you'll have to code it in JS.